# Error: /api/v0/object has been removed, use /api/v0/dag instead

Tags: javascript, nodejs, ipfs

I am using ipfs for image upload in my form it was working fine but from few days back it's giving me the error.
the following is my code.

```
uploaddoc: function(){
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onloadend = function() {
      const ipfs = window.IpfsApi({host: 'ipfs.infura.io', port: 5001, protocol: 'https'}) // Connect to IPFS
      // const ipfs = window.IpfsApi('localhost', 5001)
      // const ipfs = window.IpfsApi({ host: 'localhost', port: 5001, protocol: 'https' })

      console.log('ipfs-connection', ipfs); // checking ipfs connection

      const buf = buffer.Buffer(reader.result) // Convert to buffer
      
      ipfs.files.add(buf, (err, result) => { // Upload buffer to IPFS
      
      if(err) {
        console.error(err)
        swal("Error", "Something went wrong!", "error");
        return
      }
      let url = `https://ipfs.io/ipfs/${result[0].hash}`;

      console.log(`Url --> ${url}`);

      $(".js-uploaded-hash").attr("data-hash", result[0].hash);
      swal("Document Uploaded!", "Thanks for choosing us!", "success");
      })
    }
    const photo = document.getElementById("memories");
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(photo.files[0]); // Read Provided File

  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Luckily it's started working. I have to use the script in my HTML header.

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/ipfs-api@9.0.0/dist/index.js"
 integrity="sha384-5bXRcW9kyxxnSMbOoHzraqa7Z0PQWIao+cgeg327zit1hz5LZCEbIMx/LWKPReuB"
 crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```